# Using more than 2 options in PHP echo

Tags: php

I have the following code which works for two options,

```
<?php echo ($color) ? '#111' : '#222';?>
```

But when I try to add more, I get an error message saying unexected ":" or ";".

```
<?php echo ($color) ? '#111' : '#222' : '#333' : '#444';?>
```

How I can adapt this to work with more than two options?

Comment: Just to state the obvious here, `? :` is basically `if(true) { } else { }`.  You can only ever have two options if all you evaluate is true vs. false, regardless of the syntax or construct you may use. Based on what evaluation do you reckon your other options would ever be chosen?

Comment: Yeah I was having a blonde moment lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can chain the ternary if/else:

```php
condidition ? ifTrue : (condition2 ? if2True : (condition3 : ifTrue : ifFalse))
```

But that'll become difficult to read very fast. It's a lot easier to use elseif:

```php
if(condidition){
    ifTrue
} elseif(condidition2){
    if2True
}(condidition3){
    if3True
}
```

or a switch:

```php
switch($level){
    case "info": return 'blue';
    case "warning": return 'orange';
    case "error" :return 'red';
}
```

or with php8 a match:

```php
$color = match ($level) {
    "info" => 'blue',
    "warning" =>'orange',
    "error" => 'red',
};
```

Comment: I think this `if - else` chain would also become hard to read, and `switch` is a better alternative in this case

Comment: @tola I agree, but that only goes if there are multiple possibilities for one variable. If different checks have to be made, then an elseif is the way to go :)

Comment: you're right. I just figured, based on the question, it is a single variable in this case

Comment: All great answers, thank you, I'm really rusty haven't been hand coding for about 4-5 years, so simple things need my memory jogging.

Comment: @GibsonFX that is not how this site works :) The best answer gets the Checkbox. The reason is so the next person cant find an answer quicker. If you think an answer is good you can upvote (you can also do both). You should read it as if you dont know the author

Comment: Personally I go by how many upvotes it gets, as that's typically the consensus and could have come a significant amount of time after the author has already checked an answer, but I already checked your answer anyway.

Comment: @Martijn cheers for spelling out the alternative approaches. A simple lookup array would suffice if there are no complex conditions. As in, ```$colors = ["info" => 'blue', "warning" =>'orange', "error" => 'red', "default" => 'gray'];
echo $colors[$color] ?? $colors['default'];```. The only evaluation that needs to happen is whether a requested color exists or is null, in which case output default color. Further, maintaining your "palette" is easier and less error-prone when updating a reference array than tinkering with control structures.

Answer (score 1):

"?" - it's just a shorthand for [php if/else control structure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php).
So you can move in the way like this:

```
if ($color == 1) {
   echo '#111';
} elseif ($color == 2) {
   echo '#222'; 
}
...
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

The line you posted is basically a shortened `if` statement. It can only have 2 options (is `$color` true or false).
You can use `switch` instead - [switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)